# Django (or other pip package) in PyPy

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pypy

I am attempting to get django working using pypy. I have everything setup and working great under python2.7 and python3.2 is not installed. I then installed pypy and attempted to run django:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app_main.py", line 51, in run_toplevel
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django
```

I noticed that pypy created its own site-packages folder, so I removed that and made a symlink to the site-packages folder in my python2.7 installation. This made no change. I have also noticed that it is not just a django problem, any pip installed package doesn't work.

**python2.7 path:**

```
['', '/usr/lib/python27.zip', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11.egg-info']
```

**pypy path**

```
['', '/opt/pypy/lib_pypy/__extensions__',
'/opt/pypy/lib_pypy',
'/opt/pypy/lib-python/2.7',
'/opt/pypy/lib-python/2.7/lib-tk',
'/opt/pypy/lib-python/2.7/plat-linux2']
```

Does anyone have any experience with this? Are symlinks allowed in this situation? If not is there something else that is used instead? I also attempted just copying the django folder into the site-packages folder before deleting it but had no success with that either.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really want to create a standalone environment for your web app.  I suggest using [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) or [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/).  Managing system site-packages will bite you everytime.

Good luck!

Comment: Will using virtualenv require reinstalling everything from scratch, or does it see what I have already and do the setup for me?

Comment: I personally use buildout.  You can tell buildout to use packages from the system site-packages directory if available, or to ignore all system site-packages.  I believe virtualenv can do the same.  Doing so kinda misses the whole point though I believe -- it is best to assume you get nothing from the host system.  That will make deployment easier.